# Ubuntu as a proxy stop to comunicate to the other computers

Tags: networking, proxy

First, I will try to describe the scenario: I have an [Ubuntu Server 13](http://www.ubuntu.com/server/) as a proxy to the Internet for many other network´s equipment. In this proxy there two network cards, one of them is binds directly to a dedicated link to the Internet provider. Is also configured in this Ubuntu a pretty basic [Iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/).

Now my problem: suddenly (I not yet noticed a pattern for this event and also I have not found anything in the logs that could provide me some clue) all equipment lost communication with the proxy. Even the ping command does not find the proxy´s network cards. And this Ubuntu machine also can´t ping to the other network equipment. However, this has not lost the connection to the Internet.

My thanks to this community that helps a lot and if anyone has experienced similar problem and could share the solution ...

Comment: do you see any weird stuff when doing 'ifconfig eth0'? (assume eth0 is the backend, the one provides proxy service internally)  like RX packets with errors, dropped, ... and try to dig the 'eth0' settings with some network tools e.g. 'ethtool' to see if the setting match with your switch.

Comment: When this happen again I'll try to see anything weird in eth0 or eth1 using ifconfig and ethtool and I'll return with the results. Thanks a lot.